# Why kafka throw Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed, when spark streaming to secured kafka?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm getting this error when trying to stream from spark (using Java) to secured Kafka (with SASL PLAINTEXT mechanism).

more detailed error message:

```
17/07/07 14:38:43 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from a channel, the socket has likely been closed.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:222)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:607)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
at SparkStreaming.main(SparkStreaming.java:41)
```

Are there a specified parameters or something from kafkaParams to get spark streaming authenticated to Kafka?

back then, I added the sasl plaintext security parameter in the Kafka broker server.properties.

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
super.users=User:admin
```

here's also my kafka_jaas_server.conf

```
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin1!"
    user_admin="admin1!"
    user_aldys="admin1!";
};
```

and this is my kafka_jaas_client.conf

```
KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="aldys"
    password="admin1!";
};
```

i also include my jaas server config when start the kafka broker. via editing the kafka-server-start.sh in last line to:

```
exec $base_dir/kafka-run-class.sh $EXTRA_ARGS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_jaas_server.conf kafka.Kafka "$@"
```

using this parameter, I can produce and consume to my topic that I set ACLs before.

this is my java code

```
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class SparkStreaming {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: SparkStreaming <brokers> <topics>\n" +
                "  <brokers> is a list of one or more Kafka brokers\n" +
                "  <topics> is a list of one or more kafka topics to consume from\n\n");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String brokers = args[0];
        String topics = args[1];

        Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(topics.split(",")));

        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "group1");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
        kafkaParams.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                            .setAppName("SparkStreaming")
                            .setMaster("local[2]");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));

        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            jssc,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            kafkaParams,
            topicsSet
        );

        messages.print();

        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

also here's dependencies im using in my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is look at the logs on the kafka brokers to see if you're doing something wrong with the login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've been resolved my problem with following guide from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html.

i replaced my spark-streaming-kafka_2.11 in my pom.xml to spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11 and version 2.11.

based on error logs above in question. Im curious that the error throwed by SimpleConsumer, which SimpleConsumer is determined as an old consumer. Then i replace my pom dependencies as i said above, and change my code into following spark streaming integration guide above. Now i can stream into secured sasl plain kafka.

Comment: also include my jaas client config when running spark streaming with following guide from [here](https://medium.com/@tennysusanto/consuming-from-a-secured-kafka-with-spark-streaming-224521157747)

Answer (score 0):

Is your console producer/consumer working? If Not you should check your kafka server configs and jaas configs again.

Else, I would like you to suggest few things...

add jaas file to spark with,

`.config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions","-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/jaas.conf")
.config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/jaas.conf")`

or you can add it on spark submit with --conf

Make sure jaas file has read permission.

Must also configure the service name, which should match the principal name of the Kafka brokers.

Ex:- `kafka/hostname.com@EXAMPLE.com`

Then add,

`kafkaParams.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "kafka");`